# Ordering with condition by associated records count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm using rails 5 and I'm trying to bring all the Users order by the amount of Books read.

`users :has_many books`

I have tried

```
users = user.joins(:books).where('books.read = ?', 1).group('users.id').order("count(books.user_id)")
```

But this is removing all the users that haven't read books instead of show them last.

The column `books.read` can have several values. Users can have many or 0 books.

I want the users with books and no books orders by `books.read = 1`.

How can I achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need `LEFT JOIN` with required condition, but without `WHERE` clause

```rb
User.
  joins('LEFT JOIN books on books.user_id = users.id AND books.read = 1').
  group(:id).
  order('COUNT(books.id) DESC')
```